# Lobby Selector/Inventory Selector no longer works

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I run Minecraft on a Macintosh using Yosemite (10.10.1). My friend told me to press F3 to display coordinates to find him. After doing what my friend said, I can no longer use Lobby Select or access my inventory.

Comment: Reminder: unless you've changed this in System Preferences, alternate functions on a Mac can only be used if you hold fn while you hold the function key you wish to use.

Comment: this was recently bumped by Community, oddly, but regardless; has this situation been fixed in the time of four years?

Answer (score 1):

It may just be lag.

My recommendation: relog. If that doesn't work, turn down visual settings, I.E. Change fancy to fast, remove clouds, turn down max frame rate down, etc.

I see no reason why F3 should interfere with commands. If you think it would help, you can always turn the debug screen off by pushing F3 again.